# How do you prove the ideal $I= (X^2, XY)$ has infinitely many distinct irredundant primary decompositions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, monomial-ideals

I have come up with the following two different decompositions of the ideal $I= (X^2, XY)$:
 $I = (X) \cap (X^2, Y)$ and $I = (X) \cap (X^2, XY, Y^2) = (X) \cap (X, Y)^2$.

Can we generalize this somehow so that there are are infinitely many different primary decompositions?

Comment: What is the ring of this ideal? Does being able to be decomposed in infinitely many ways have any relation with the ring on which the ideal is defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. $I=(X) \cap (X^2, XY, Y^n) $, for all $n\in \Bbb N$.

Comment: This answer is helpful. Thanks.

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: @user 1 Can this(or any other) primary decomposition be uncountably infinite?