# Easy explanation on primary decomposition of ideals.

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, monomial-ideals

The primary decomposition of an ideal $(x^2, xy)$ is 
$$(x^2, xy) = (x) \cap (x, y)^2$$
which can be found on [these notes](http://people.brandeis.edu/~igusa/Math205bS10/Math205b_S10_41.pdf).

---

Could someone explain to me how this can be done?

---

Edited: My question is not restricted to the example I gave  $(x^2, xy)$,  one can use any other example to show me the process.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990898/primary-decomposition-of-x2-xy-xz-in-kx-y-z-where-k-is-a-field, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1688151/how-do-you-prove-the-ideal-i-x2-xy-has-infinitely-many-distinct-irredunda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer 1.**`In general, to see an illustration of primary decomposition:`
The book "Monomial Ideals" by "Herzog-Hibi", section 1.3 (Primary decomposition and associated prime ideals) illustrate this. The book has:
"Theorem 1.3.1 in combination with Corollary 1.3.2 now says that each monomial ideal has a unique presentation as an irredundant intersection of irreducible (primary) monomial ideals.  The proof of Theorem 1.3.1 shows us how we can find such a presentation." [Example 1.3.3](https://books.google.com/books?id=3PxzYIBTibsC&q=Example+1.3.3#v=snippet&q=Example%201.3.3&f=false) illustrates the procedure.
I add an image of Example 1.3.3 and highlight the first step:
[image]

> So we have  $(x^2, xy) = (x^2, x)\cap (x^2,y)    =  (x) \cap (x^2, y)$

---

**Answer 2.** `For your special example:`
Let K be a field and let R = K[X,Y]. Let M=(X,Y). The book "Steps in Commutative Algebra" by "Sharp", shows ([Example 4.27, page 74](https://books.google.com/books?id=Oi4x9NznFEUC&q=Let+K+be+a+field+and+let+R+%3D+K%5BX%2CY%5D+be+the+ring+of+polynomials+over+K+in+indeterminates+X%2C+Y#v=snippet&q=EXAMPLE.%20Let%20K%20be%20a%20field%20and%20let%20R%20%3D%20K%5BX%2CY%5D%20be%20the%20ring%20of%20polynomials&f=false)) that $I=(x^2, xy) = (x) \cap (x, y)^2=(x) \cap (x^2, y)$. So the primary decomposition of "answer 1" and the primary decomposition you want are both primary decompositions for $I$.

Comment: In this case the answer would be $$(x^2, xy) = (x^2,x) \cap (x^2, y)=(x)\cap(x^2,y)$$ (It is fine but) why do we need to replace $(x^2,y)$ by $(x,y)^2=(x^2,xy,y^2)$

Comment: 1- primary decomposition is not unique. 2-    we dont replace $(x^2,y)$ by $(x^2,xy,y^2)$, but we replace $(x)\cap (x^2,y)$ by $ (x)\cap (x^2,xy,y^2)$. 3- we dont *need* to replace. +  give a link for "which can be found all over this site"

Comment: There are even [more decompositions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1688151/how-do-you-prove-the-ideal-i-x2-xy-has-infinitely-many-distinct-irredunda?rq=1)