# On the height of a square-free monomial ideal in a five variable polynomial ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension, monomial-ideals

> Consider the monomial ideal $I=(vw,wx,xy,yz,zv)$ in the polynomial ring $k[v,w,x,y,z]$. How do we find the height of the ideal $I$ ?

Since $5=\dim k[v,w,x,y,z]=\mathrm{ht}(I)+ \dim (k[v,w,x,y,z]/I)$, so equivalently asking, how to find the Krull dimension of the ring   $k[v,w,x,y,z]/I$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the algorithms in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/628586/) and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1793879/), we can compute a primary decomposition for $I$:
$$
I = (v,x,y) \cap (v,x,z) \cap (w,y,z) \cap (v,w,y) \cap (w,x,z) \, .
$$
Indeed, this shows that $I$ is an intersection of prime ideals (hence is radical). Each of these minimal primes has height $3$, so $I$ also has height $3$.