# Primary decomposition for an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, primary-decomposition

I can find primary decomposition of ideal generated by two elements . For example ideal $\langle xy, y^2\rangle=\langle x, y^2\rangle  \cap \langle y\rangle $ 
But I face problem when I tried to find primary decomposition of the ideal $\langle x^3, x^2y, yz, xz^2\rangle $  in $K[x, y, z]$ . Can someone help me how can I find primary decomposition of ideal which is generated by 4 elements?

Thanks.

Comment: See this post, too: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1793841/

Comment: Thank you very much guys